# Resolve quadratic equation in prolog

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I got problem with quadrating equation implementation in prolog.
I know some basics but at same point I can not understand output of swish.swi console.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions from your side about my errors.

```
delta(A, B, C, D):- D is B*B - 4*A*C.

equation(A,B,C,X):- D1<0,delta(A,B,C,D1),X is 0. % or false... but how to retur false there?
equation(A,B,C,X):- D1 =:= 0,delta(A,B,C,D1),X is -B/2*A. 
equation(A,B,C,X): D1>0,delta(A,B,C,D1),X is -B-sqrt(D1)/2*A.
equation(A,B,C,X): D1>0,delta(A,B,C,D1),X is -B+sqrt(D1)/2*A.
```

I am getting two errors there after runnign `equation(2, 0, 1, X).`

```
Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2
</2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about

> Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

you must swap delta/4 and the test. Also, it's better to use if/then/else, to avoid recomputing the result:

```
equation(A,B,C,X) :-
 delta(A,B,C,D1),
 (  D1 < 0
 -> X is 0
 ;  D1 =:= 0
 -> X is -B/2*A
 ;  X is -B-sqrt(D1)/2*A
 ).
```

Comment: But can we return `false` or sth similar to that in first case when `D1<0`? Yes we can :) we have to do sth like that
 `...(  D1 < 0
 -> !,fail
 ;  ...`

Answer (score 1):

At the last 2 predicates (the ones where D>0), you forgot to write "-" after ":". Your code works good, it was just a sintax error. Below I corrected the code for you:

```
delta(A, B, C, D):- D is B*B - 4*A*C.
equation(A,B,C,X):- D1<0, delta(A,B,C,D1), X is 0. 
equation(A,B,C,X):- D1 =:= 0, delta(A,B,C,D1), X is -B/2*A.
equation(A,B,C,X):- delta(A,B,C,D1), D1>0, X is ((-1*B-sqrt(D1))/2*A).
equation(A,B,C,X):- delta(A,B,C,D1), D1>0, X is ((-1*B+sqrt(D1))/2*A).
```